# BAQ calculated field SQL editor

Tags: epicor

Getting this error message while trying to build a BAQ:

Column 'Inventory Quanity.PlantWhse_Plant' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Column 'Quantity Moved.PlantWhse1_Plant' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any ideas?

Trying to add a Part Description column and now everything is failing

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to SQL, if you're using various types of calculations in your select statement, your fields may have to be grouped.

Go to Query Builder > Display Fields > Column Select and check the Group By field.

Without more context or the code from your BAQ it's hard to be more precise than that.

[image]